How to use vuetify readonly prop but still allow selection menu
I have a grid of v-autocomplete components which have a multiple attribute added. However, to try and keep the formating clean I shorten the length of whats shown by using the selection slot as shown:
          <v-autocomplete
        v-model="programModel"
        multiple
        density="compact"
        variant="outlined"
        hide-details
        color="primary"
        flat
        rounded
        label="Programs"
        :items="programData"
        item-title="program_name"
        return-object
        :rules="arrayRequiredRule"
        :readonly="!editableTopSectionModel"
      >
      <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
        <span v-if="!index">{{ item.title }}</span>
        <span class="grey--text caption" v-else-if="index === 1">
          &nbsp;(+ {{programModel!.length - 1}} others)
        </span>
      </template>
    </v-autocomplete>

However, my form there is a button that will activate whether the v-autocompletes are editable or not by toggling readonly. The issue is if it is readonly true then a user cannot click the dropdown to see the potential options. Its unclear how to get around this to make this functional.

Why do we need the readonly attribute? You do not want the user to type a customized option?

Yea the section is more for display until they hit the editable option. Its kind of like a small form at the top of a page that has data for user to see and they can edit but we put locks on it depending on the user. SO I have a button with a pencil to allow editing then saving the submitted data.



      <v-autocomplete
        v-model="programModel"
        multiple
        density="compact"
        variant="outlined"
        hide-details
        color="primary"
        flat
        rounded
        label="Programs"
        :items="programData"
        item-title="program_name"
        return-object
        :rules="arrayRequiredRule"
        :readonly="!editableTopSectionModel"
      >
      <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index }">
        <span v-if="!index">{{ item.title }}</span>
        <span class="grey--text caption" v-else-if="index === 1">
          &nbsp;(+ {{programModel!.length - 1}} others)
        </span>
      </template>
    </v-autocomplete>



Also try to set editableTopSectionModel false default and then try to update the flag

Why is return-object set to false in your answer?

can you send the where you are assigning "programModel"
so, i can suggest the soultion

I guess my example has so much details. But really it could be any object nestled as a v-model and data.
